# Why can I read uncommited changes?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-transactions

I have two simple methods. First - writes a new Person in a table, but does not commit changes.
Second - reads names of all people in the table.

Why does my second method is able to read uncommited changes, though I have TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED?

```java
public class Base {
    private static final String URL= "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    private static final String USERNAME = "postgres";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "12345";

    private static Connection connection;
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    initialInsert(); // writes a new name but does not commit
    readUncommited(); // reads the "name" parameter in a table
    
    }


    public static void initialInsert() {


        String SQL = "INSERT INTO Person VALUES(?,?,?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1,1);

            preparedStatement.setString(2,"Mike");
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,32);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void readUncommited() {
        String SQL2Read = "SELECT * FROM Person";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL2Read);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name"));

        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Because everything happens in the same connection/transaction

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thank you! I have to ask you a one more dumb question.How am i supposed to make it work. So that uncommited changes can't be accesed by other methods.

Comment: Wait a second... I thought whenever you're acting outside a transaction, that all changes/commits are permanent unless they fail... And you wrap it all up into a transaction if you have multiple commits that either have all to be valid to be committed finally, and that if any one fails all changes are rewound / not permanent. So I think the problem here is to wrap your actions explicitly into transactions to get the desired behaviour...? And I do not see a transaction bein allocated, so the code works as it should... IMO

Comment: You are probably going to have to either implement your own system to flag if data is 'available' or use mutliple connection contexts. As far as the database is concerned everything is being done by "you" and you would expect to have your uncommitted changes visible throughout.

Comment: @JayC667 The OP disabled auto-commit mode, which means JDBC will start a transaction when necessary, and you're responsible to commit or rollback. You always work in a transaction in a database, though sometimes the transaction might be started and committed transparently in the background for you ('auto-commit mode'). Without a transaction, the database wouldn't know what visibility guarantees it has to provide.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Wow! Thanx a lot for clearing that up! Learned something new again today :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can read uncommitted changes because those changes are read in the same transaction that wrote them. The fact a transaction can see its own uncommitted changes is normal and expected.

If you had used separate connections (and thus separate transactions), you wouldn't have been able to see those changes (unless you were using a non-transactional database like MySQL with the MyISAM storage negine instead of InnoDB).